# estou criando um app de cadastro em flutter e está dando este erro o que devo fazer? alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

Tags: flutter

Uma string não nula deve ser fornecida a um widget de texto.
'package: flutter / src / widgets / text.dart':
Asserção falhada: linha 360 pos 10: 'dados! = Nulo'

Comment: Quando você tenta usar uma variável para setar um texto a um _Widget_ Text() é preciso que a variável não esteja nula... Sete o valor da seguinte forma `Text(minhaVariavel ?? "")`... Isso fará que se caso a variavel for nula, seja setado um valor em branco.

Comment: ok muito obrigada.

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando utilizar um widget de texto com valor null. Verifique se o valor está vindo corretamente e caso o valor só seja atualizado após o widget for renderizado, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
Text(variavel != null ? variavel : null)
```

Comment: ok muito obrigada.